# Issues reading accelerometer data from Mpu9150

Tags: android, linux, accelerometer, android-sensors, mpu

I am trying to get accelerometer data from mpu9150 and pass it to android for screen rotation.

My initialization is as follows:

1. Reset Mpu9150
2. Clear sleep bit
3. Set Sample Rate Divider to 7 (for 1KHz)
4. Set DLPD to 260Hz
5. Configuring INT pin condition and enabling Data Ready interrupt

With this configuration I am able to get data and I am even able to get screen rotation.

But the problem is I am getting some junk data in the middle. (Probably this may be due to reading of user-read only registers while mpu is updating those registers with its internal set of registers.)
I want this problem to be eliminated as we are giving corrupted data sometimes which causes me a problem when I use it with the compass.

Suggest me to solve this If anyone is aware of this issue.

The Log looks something like this.

```
MPU9150 Accelerometer Sensor Loaded

0:0xfffffff4 1:0xffffffbc 2:0x2 3:0xfffffff4 4:0xffffffbd 5:0x2c 

ax:-68      ay:-12      az:-17108

0:0xfffffff4 1:0x40 2:0x2 3:0xffffffec 4:0xffffffbd 5:0x1c 

ax:-3008        ay:-20      az:-17124

0:0xfffffff4 1:0x48 2:0x2 3:0xffffffc0 4:0xffffffbc 5:0xffffffc8 

ax:-3000        ay:-64      az:-56

0:0xfffffff4 1:0x70 2:0x3 3:0x44 4:0xffffffbc 5:0xffffffa0 

ax:-2960        ay:836      az:-96

0:0xfffffff4 1:0x64 2:0x3 3:0x1c 4:0xffffffbc 5:0xffffffc0 

ax:-2972        ay:796      az:-64

0:0xfffffff4 1:0xffffffa0 2:0x3 3:0x20 4:0xffffffbd 5:0xffffff84 

ax:-96      ay:800      az:-124

0:0xfffffff4 1:0x40 2:0x2 3:0xffffffcc 4:0xffffffbc 5:0xffffffac 

ax:-3008        ay:-52      az:-84


0:0xfffffff4 1:0x74 2:0x2 3:0xffffffd4 4:0xffffffbc 5:0xffffffc4 

ax:-2956        ay:-44      az:-60

0:0xfffffff4 1:0x1c 2:0x2 3:0xffffffb8 4:0xffffffbc 5:0xffffffa8 

ax:-3044        ay:-72      az:-88

0:0xfffffff4 1:0x78 2:0x2 3:0xfffffff0 4:0xffffffbd 5:0x10 

ax:-2952        ay:-16      az:-17136

0:0xfffffff4 1:0x38 2:0x2 3:0xffffff90 4:0xffffffbc 5:0xffffffac 

ax:-3016        ay:-112     az:-84

0:0xfffffff4 1:0x50 2:0x2 3:0xffffffe8 4:0xffffffbd 5:0x34 

ax:-2992        ay:-24      az:-17100

0:0xfffffff4 1:0xffffff9c 2:0x2 3:0xffffff98 4:0xffffffbc 5:0xffffffc8 

ax:-100     ay:-104     az:-56

0:0xfffffff4 1:0xffffffdc 2:0x2 3:0xffffffdc 4:0xffffffbc 5:0xfffffffc 

ax:-36      ay:-36      az:-4

0:0xfffffff4 1:0x60 2:0x3 3:0x24 4:0xffffffbc 5:0x7c 

ax:-2976        ay:804      az:-17284

0:0xfffffff4 1:0x18 2:0x2 3:0xffffff9c 4:0xffffffbd 5:0x0 

ax:-3048        ay:-100     az:-17152

0:0xfffffff4 1:0x74 2:0x2 3:0xfffffff0 4:0xffffffbc 5:0xffffffe4 

ax:-2956        ay:-16      az:-28

0:0xfffffff4 1:0x58 2:0x2 3:0xffffffcc 4:0xffffffbc 5:0xffffffcc 

ax:-2984        ay:-52      az:-52

0:0xfffffff4 1:0xffffffac 2:0x2 3:0xffffffe0 4:0xffffffbc 5:0xffffffa4 

ax:-84      ay:-32      az:-92

0:0xfffffff4 1:0x38 2:0x2 3:0xffffff84 4:0xffffffbd 5:0xffffffb4 

ax:-3016        ay:-124     az:-76

0:0xfffffff4 1:0x58 2:0x2 3:0xffffffc0 4:0xffffffbc 5:0xffffffb0 

ax:-2984        ay:-64      az:-80

0:0xfffffff4 1:0xffffffa4 2:0x2 3:0xffffffcc 4:0xffffffbc 5:0xffffff88 

ax:-92      ay:-52      az:-120

0:0xfffffff4 1:0xffffff94 2:0x2 3:0xffffffc0 4:0xffffffbc 5:0xfffffff0 

ax:-108     ay:-64      az:-16
```

Regards,

Shyam Kumar.